# Verifying method call with any struct parameter in Moq

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, moq

I'm running into the following problem when migrating my app from ASP.NET Core 2.2 to ASP.NET Core 3.0:

I have a class which should log an error message under certain circumstances. This is done by calling `LogError` on `ILogger<MyClass>`.

I used to verifiy this with the following snippet from my unit test:

```cs
Mock<ILogger<MyClass>> loggerMock = ...;
MyClass myClass = ...;

myClass.MethodThatLogsTestException();

loggerMock.Verify(l => l.Log(
    It.IsAny<LogLevel>(),
    It.IsAny<EventId>(),
    It.IsAny<object>(),
    It.IsAny<TestException>(),
    It.IsAny<Func<object, Exception, string>>())
);
```

Now here lies the problem:

In ASP.NET Core 2.2, the 3rd parameter (Mocked via `It.IsAny<object>()`) was of an internal type `FormattedLogValues`. This was a class, so `It.IsAny<object>()` worked. In ASP.NET Core 3.0 it was changed to a struct, so `It.IsAny<object>()` no longer matches it.

How can I get my `Verify()` call to work in ASP.NET Core 3.0? Is there an `It.IsAny()` version that matches any struct type?

Edit:
Here is a fully runnable snippet that fails on ASP.NET Core 3.0 and succeeds on ASP.NET Core 2.2.

```cs
public class Test
{
    public class Impl
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Impl> logger;

        public Impl(ILogger<Impl> logger)
        {
            this.logger = logger;
        }

        public void Method()
        {
            logger.LogError(new Exception(), "An error occurred.");
        }
    }

    [Fact]
    public void LogsErrorOnException()
    {
        var loggerMock = new Mock<ILogger<Impl>>();
        var sut = new Impl(loggerMock.Object);

        sut.Method();

        loggerMock.Verify(l => l.Log(
            It.IsAny<LogLevel>(),
            It.IsAny<EventId>(),
            It.IsAny<object>(),
            It.IsAny<Exception>(),
            It.IsAny<Func<object, Exception, string>>())
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Which moq version are you using? The very latest one(4.13) has the `It.IsAnyType`, not sure if that could help but I think it is worth trying...

Comment: I can use the latest version (was on an older version). IsAnyStype still doesn't seem to work.: I've tried replacing both objects with `It.IsAnyType` and still receive the same error. (Invocation was never performed). It seemed like it should work!

Comment: What is the error message when the test fails? Because In terms of inheritance it looks like `struct -> ValueType -> Object`, `class -> Object` and I suppose your test should work

Comment: The error message is: `Expected invocation on the mock at least once, but was never performed: l => l.Log<object>(It.IsAny<LogLevel>(), It.IsAny<EventId>(), It.IsAny<It.IsAnyType>(), It.IsAny<TestException>(), It.IsAny<Func<object, Exception, string>>())`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Changing `It.IsAny<Func<object, Exception, string>>())` to `(Func<object, Exception, string>) It.IsAny<object>()` seems to solve the problem. `object`  can also be replace by `IsAnyType` if you're on Moq 4.13+.

Internally the Logger class uses `FormattedLogValues` as the state parameter (the `object` in my example). The change to struct seems to have something to do with it. What exactly the cause is I'm not sure. But there seems to be an issue on the Moq GitHub repo describing a few more details. There doesn't seem to be a concrete explanation yet why it used to work, but more info will probably be posted there soon.

https://github.com/moq/moq4/issues/918

Answer (score 4):

I found the same problem in [Github](https://github.com/moq/moq4/issues/918).

I made an extension method for the solution:

```
public static void VerifyLog<T>(this Mock<ILogger<T>> mockLogger, Func<Times> times)
{
    mockLogger.Verify(x => x.Log(
        It.IsAny<LogLevel>(),
        It.IsAny<EventId>(),
        It.Is<It.IsAnyType>((v, t) => true),
        It.IsAny<Exception>(),
        It.Is<Func<It.IsAnyType, Exception, string>>((v, t) => true)), times);
}
```