# Setting up returns with generic parameters

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

So using Moq to try and do unit tests, I have something like this method I'm trying to mock:

```
Task<S> UseFooAsync<S>(Func<T, S> func);
```

And I can set it up, for a specific case, like this:

```
data.Setup(r => r.UseFooAsync(It.IsAny<Func<DB, MyBar>>()))
    .Returns(Func<DB, MyBar> f => Task.FromResult(f(myMockObj.Object));
```

For the case where I specify all the generic type parameters. And I can confirm it works because in my test I can do:

```
myMockObj.Verify(m => m.SomeFunction(), Times.Once);
```

Which will verify that the function that I supplied my mock `myMockObj` to tried to call a function on that object.

But I'd like to make it more generic. So I tried this:

```
data.Setup(r => r.UseFooAsync(It.IsAny<Func<DB, It.IsAnyType>>()))
    .Returns((Func<DB, It.IsAnyType> f) => Task.FromResult(f(myMockObj.Object)));
```

And this compiles just fine, but in my test, it seems to not get the `myMockObj` so my verify fails. Does anybody know why? Is it possible to make this work generically? Or am I resigned to having to setup for each generic parameter type I need to mock for the purpose of my unit test(s)?

Comment: Could this be linked to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57989318/verifying-method-call-with-any-struct-parameter-in-moq